# Changing the date format not working in ng-grid angular js

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, jsp, web

I am using ng-grid table for my UI.
This has one of the Date column. I am sending the date value in yyyy/mm/dd format but on UI it showing in yyyy/mm/dd 00:00:00 format. I am not sure where its getting change.
Moreover I tried changing its format using cellFilter but this also not seems to working.

Here are my JS code:

```js
columnDefs: [{ field: "HostName", width: 120, pinned: true, cellTemplate: linkCellTemplate  },
      { field: "SerialNumber", width: 120 },
   { field: "StartDate", width: 160, displayName:"Warranty Start Date" },
   { field: "ExpDate", width: 160,displayName:"WarrantyExpDate",cellFilter: "WarrantyExpDate:\'yyyy/MM/dd\'"},
             { field: "DateReceived", width: 130, displayName:"Date Received"  },
             ...........
             
             }
```

Please Help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note above code is not complete code , it is just part of the code where i used cellFilter.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
cellFilter: "WarrantyExpDate:\'yyyy/MM/dd\'"
```

to this:

```
cellFilter: "date:\'yyyy/MM/dd\'"
```